# Apache/Nginx: proxy POST requests to remote server, handle OPTIONS requests locally

Tags: apache, proxy, nginx, cors

I am trying to configure Apache to act as a proxy to a remote server, to allow cross-domain AJAX using [CORS](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/cross-site-xmlhttprequest-with-cors/). To achieve this, I need Apache to respond to 2 HTTP verbs, like so:

1. OPTIONS:
   Respond to this CORS 'pre-flight' request with some simple HTTP headers. I had in mind that this could be a simple CGI script ([options.pl](https://gist.github.com/17698f66e6305682a1dc)).
2. POST:
   Proxy all POST requests to the remote server, but add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" header to allow the cross-domain request to happen.

I can achieve both of these requirements independently, but I cannot configure Apache to do both. The problem is that when the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse is configured, the OPTIONS requests no longer hit the CGI script, they are proxied to the remote server.

My current config is below. I'd like to solve this with a pure web-server solution e.g. Apache/Nginx (rather than running some application code), if possible.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Location "/">

        # Disallow all verbs except OPTIONS and POST
        order deny,allow
        deny from all

        # OPTIONS should be handled by a local CGI script
        <Limit OPTIONS>
            allow from all
            Script OPTIONS /cgi-bin/options.pl
        </Limit>

        # POST requests are proxied to a remote server
        <Limit POST>
            allow from all
            ProxyPass http://somewhere-else/
            ProxyPassReverse http://somewhere-else/
            Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </Limit>

    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how I've solved it using Nginx. Note that I am using the [Headers More](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersMoreModule) module which required me to [compile Nginx from source](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxInstallOptions).

```
location / {

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS';
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000';
        more_set_headers 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';

        return 200;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *';
        proxy_pass http://somewhere-else;
    }
}
```

Comment: how did you install more_set_headers , as nginx is installed on my server from installer

Answer (score 4):

You can use my nginx_cross_origin_module now. It supports the full CORS feature: https://github.com/yaoweibin/nginx_cross_origin_module

Example:

```
http {

    cors on;
    cors_max_age     3600;
    cors_origin_list unbounded;
    cors_method_list GET HEAD PUT POST;
    cors_header_list unbounded;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }
}
```